# Canvas gradient is diagonal when it should be vertical

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, gradient

I have some javascript code to generate a gradient from 14 colors:

```js
var example = document.getElementById('example');
var context = example.getContext('2d');

var grdBnds = [0, 0, 200, 30]
var grd = context.createLinearGradient(grdBnds[0], grdBnds[1], grdBnds[2], grdBnds[3]);
grd.addColorStop((1/14)*0, "rgb(0, 0, 0)");
grd.addColorStop((1/14)*1, "rgb(191, 191, 191)");
grd.addColorStop((1/14)*2, "rgb(115, 115, 115)");
grd.addColorStop((1/14)*3, "rgb(245, 182, 181)");
grd.addColorStop((1/14)*4, "rgb(147, 252, 253)");
grd.addColorStop((1/14)*5, "rgb(87, 120, 246)");
grd.addColorStop((1/14)*6, "rgb(177, 251, 162)");
grd.addColorStop((1/14)*7, "rgb(80, 176, 51)");
grd.addColorStop((1/14)*8, "rgb(230, 230, 75)");
grd.addColorStop((1/14)*9, "rgb(187, 109, 93)");
grd.addColorStop((1/14)*10, "rgb(235, 51, 35)");
grd.addColorStop((1/14)*11, "rgb(188, 39, 246)");
grd.addColorStop((1/14)*12, "rgb(117, 20, 124)");
grd.addColorStop((1/14)*13, "rgb(191, 191, 191)");

context.fillStyle = grd;
context.fillRect(grdBnds[0], grdBnds[1], grdBnds[2], grdBnds[3]);
```

```html
<canvas id="example" width="1000" height="400"></canvas>
```

As you can see, the gradient lines are being generated at a diagonal angle to the right, when they should be going vertically.

Does anybody know why this is happening, and how I could fix it?

I know you can also make gradients with CSS, but for what I am doing I need to make the vertical gradients with `canvas`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createLinearGradient` generate a gradient from two points, (x0,y0) and (x1, y1). This is why it takes four parameters.

`fillStyle` defines the color, gradiant or pattern used by `fillRect` to fill your rectangle. You are using gradiant here.

`fillRect` takes four parameters: `x`, `y`, `width`, and `height`.

Here is a snippet that uses the canvas dimensions to set the different parameters.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('example');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var colors = [
    "rgb(0, 0, 0)",
    "rgb(191, 191, 191)",
    "rgb(115, 115, 115)",
    "rgb(245, 182, 181)",
    "rgb(147, 252, 253)",
    "rgb(87, 120, 246)",
    "rgb(177, 251, 162)",
    "rgb(80, 176, 51)",
    "rgb(230, 230, 75)",
    "rgb(187, 109, 93)",
    "rgb(235, 51, 35)",
    "rgb(188, 39, 246)",
    "rgb(117, 20, 124)",
    "rgb(191, 191, 191)"
];

// Horizontally
var grd = context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, canvas.width, 0);

// Vertically
var grd = context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, canvas.height);

for (let index = 0; index < colors.length; index++) {
    const color = colors[index];
    grd.addColorStop(index/colors.length, color);
}

context.fillStyle = grd;
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

```html
<canvas id="example" width="1000" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: This is an awesome answer, very helpful. I appreciate the idea to use `canvas.width` and `canvas.height`, it is certainly better to use these values than any static value.

Answer (score 1):

The parameters to `createLinearGradient` and `fillRect` are 2 different things.

```js
var example = document.getElementById('example');
var context = example.getContext('2d');

var grdBnds = [0, 0, 000, 240]
var rectBnds = [0, 0, 360, 240]
var grd = context.createLinearGradient(grdBnds[0], grdBnds[1], grdBnds[2], grdBnds[3]);
grd.addColorStop((1 / 14) * 0, "rgb(0, 0, 0)");
grd.addColorStop((1 / 14) * 1, "rgb(191, 191, 191)");
grd.addColorStop((1 / 14) * 2, "rgb(115, 115, 115)");
grd.addColorStop((1 / 14) * 3, "rgb(245, 182, 181)");
grd.addColorStop((1 / 14) * 4, "rgb(147, 252, 253)");
grd.addColorStop((1 / 14) * 5, "rgb(87, 120, 246)");
grd.addColorStop((1 / 14) * 6, "rgb(177, 251, 162)");
grd.addColorStop((1 / 14) * 7, "rgb(80, 176, 51)");
grd.addColorStop((1 / 14) * 8, "rgb(230, 230, 75)");
grd.addColorStop((1 / 14) * 9, "rgb(187, 109, 93)");
grd.addColorStop((1 / 14) * 10, "rgb(235, 51, 35)");
grd.addColorStop((1 / 14) * 11, "rgb(188, 39, 246)");
grd.addColorStop((1 / 14) * 12, "rgb(117, 20, 124)");
grd.addColorStop((1 / 14) * 13, "rgb(191, 191, 191)");

context.fillStyle = grd;
context.fillRect(rectBnds[0], rectBnds[1], rectBnds[2], rectBnds[3]);
```

```html
<canvas id="example" width="1000" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the answer! I can get it horizontally by doing `var grdBnds = [0, 0, 390, 0]` and `var rectBnds = [0, 0, 360, 30]`.